# Find element with selenium by display text

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I am trying to hover over an element in a menu bar with selenium, but having difficulty locating the element. The element is displayed below :

```
<DIV onmouseover="function(blah blah);" class=mainItem>TextToFind</DIV>
```

There are multiple elements of this type so I need to find this element by `TextToFind`.

I've tried :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("TextToFind"))
```

and

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("TextToFind"))
```

which both didn't work. I even tried:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("mainItem"))
```

which also did not work. Can someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 20):

You are using incorrect syntax of xpath in `By.Xpath` and `By.LinkText` works only on `a` element with text and `By.ClassName` looks ok but may be there are more elements with that class name that's why you couldn't get right element, So you should try use below provided xPath with text :-

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text() = 'TextToFind']"));
```

Or

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[. = 'TextToFind']"));
```

Or

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(., 'TextToFind')]"));
```

Hope it works...:)

Comment: For the life of me I can't get this to work.

C#:
    var x = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text() = 'Applications']"));
HTML:
    <span class="nav-text">Applications</span>

Answer (score 2):

Better ignoring the whitespaces around the text with this:

```
var elm = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[normalize-space() = 'TextToFind']"));
```

This searches text within an [a] element, you can replace it with any element you are interested in (div, span etc.).