# Selenium C# - FindElement with dynamically changing id attribute

Tags: c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to Find Element that are dynamically changing.
Eg.,

```
<span id="ygtvlabelel105" class="ygtvlabel gticon-f214_casesTree-0">LLB Application</span>
```

Is it possible to find element using the text in the above '`LLB Application`'?

```
var element = Driver.FindElement(By.??????("//a[contains(text(), 'LLB Application')]"));
```

XPath only contains the text in Id's i'e'., `//*[@id="ygtvlabelel105"]` and the number changes every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find element with selenium by display text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661830/find-element-with-selenium-by-display-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided to locate the element you can use either of the the following *Locator Strategy* :

- `CssSelector` :

  ```
  var element = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.ygtvlabel.gticon-f214_casesTree-0[id^='ygtvlabelel']"));
  ```
- `XPath` :

  ```
  var element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='ygtvlabel gticon-f214_casesTree-0' and starts-with(@id,'ygtvlabelel')]"));
  ```
- `XPath` with more granularity using text **LLB Application** :

  ```
  var element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='ygtvlabel gticon-f214_casesTree-0' and starts-with(@id,'ygtvlabelel') and contains(.,'LLB Application')]"));
  ```

Comment: thanks DebanjanB, it worked - really appreciate your help - i used var element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='ygtvlabel gticon-f214_casesTree-0' and starts-with(@id,'ygtvlabelel') and contains(.,'LLB Application')]"));

Comment: I tried to do that last night when i replied to you but it says that it'll be considered but as i'm new to this forum, it'll allow me only after reaching 15 points.